# How to normalize a histogram with Danfo.js?

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, visualization, data-analysis, danfojs

I need to get normalized histogram.
So in [Danfo notebooks](https://playnotebook.jsdata.org) I tried syntax like this:

```js
s = new dfd.Series([1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 6, 10, 10, 34, 40, 51, 90, 90, 90, 90, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 6, 10, 10, 34, 40, 51, 90, 90, 90, 90, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 6, 10, 10, 34, 40, 51, 90, 90, 90, 90, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 6, 10, 10, 34, 40, 51, 90, 90, 90, 90, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 6, 10, 10, 34, 40, 51, 90, 90, 90, 90, 75]) 
s.plot(this_div()).hist({histnorm: 'probability', layout: {title: 'Normalized Histogram'}})
```

But it looks like danfo.js ignores [Plotly `histnorm` trace attribute](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/histogram/#histogram-histnorm).

So the question is: Is it possible to use Plotly trace attributes with danfojs's plots, and if it's possible then what is correct syntax for that?